# Simplex method on graphs: How do I find a basic solution using the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm?

Tags: linear-programming, graphs, network-flow, reduced-costs

I'm tasked with solving a minimal cost flow problem. I'm asked to first use the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm on my graph to find a basic solution that will then be used to do the simplex method on that graph.

Once I found the maximum possible flow I can have for my graph with the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm, do I use this information to get a basic solution for the simplex method? A basic solution is a partial tree that is linked to all the nodes in the graph, right?

Because I have multiple sources and multiple destinations in my graph. I made a super source and a super destination and then applied the Ford-Fulkerson algorithm. When trying to find the basic solution what do I do with these nodes? Do I simply revert back to the original graph?

Comment: This is not an answer but it is interesting that are no answers to this question after two years.
I am having a similar issue and was hoping to find some answers. Seems that I will have to go back to my old notes (who knows where they are!) of Operations Research to find out how this was done. If I get them I will post it here.

Comment: Like Warm-start?